# css3 transform:scale doesn't work in Safari

Tags: css, animation

try to make this effect to work, is working fine on chrome and opera but not working on safari or firefox.

what is wrong?

I used on a span tag on my html code

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
       -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    } 
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

.take {
    margin-left: 40px;
    color: #c8262d;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
    animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="take">Take Action Today &DDotrahd;</span>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle demonstrating your code?

Comment: Some HTML always helps to add context to CSS.

Comment: I fix it by changing span tag for div and adding     width: 300px;
    float: right;

Comment: If `.take` is applied to a `span` without making that span a block element, it won't work as expected. This is why swapping for a `div` (which _is_ a block element) works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `display:block;` to your `.take` rule

```
.take {
    margin-left: 40px;
    color: #c8262d;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
    animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28q6cy2j/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is in the specs (*see: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#terminology*)

> **transformable element**
>      A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is **either a block-level or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)**, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform [SVG11].

So you will have to give your element a `display:inline-block` since it is a `span` (*inline by default*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/p70o9r08/

---

The same holds for the `width`/`height` properties you have on your rule. They also will not apply to inline elements.